# Sending image through email intent permissions or not able to locate file?

Tags: android, image, email, android-intent, bitmap

I am capturing a relativelayout's drawing cache and saving it to a file. The file has been tested and is there. Using this file, I am sending an image as an email attachment however it isn't working. Before it used to say that it couldn't be found because of the improper path however I fixed that and now there are no errors in the logcat. Would this be caused by a lack of permissions, not being able to locate the file or is sending email image attachments unsupported by Android?

**Saving the Image**

```
    ImagePlace.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap picture = ImagePlace.getDrawingCache();
    try {       
    System.out.println(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir());
picture.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream(new File(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),"asdasdasdasdasdas.jpg")));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch blockm
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Starting the E-Mail Intent**

```
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent.setType("image/*");
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Projectile Motion Solution");
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(html));
 // emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.raw.background));
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"asdasdasdasdasdas.jpg"));
  startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: I also tried to use an Image Tag (Add it as HTML) and got the same problem. It doesn't give me a file not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Uri.parse("file://" + path to File));
instead
Of
Uri.parse(this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"asdasdasdasdasdas.jpg"));

Comment: Still didn't work. It gave me the null image icon as my thumbnail in the attachment.

Comment: Are you able to see the saved image in ur device?

Comment: As a thumbnail but I can't open it.

Comment: okay so may be the file format is not supported by it or the file is corrupted.Try sending a valid jpeg stored somewhere in your memory card.. via the intent